# Linked List node tail doesn't update when adding new nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm playing around with pointers for a Linked List class project, and can't wrap my head around how to create a link to a new node. I have a `Linked List` class which contains methods like `append` to manipulate the data structure. I want the nodes to be bids which are read from a csv file.

When I load all the data from the csv, I would like to

1. create a new bid
2. pass the new bid to the `append` function
3. set the nextBid pointer of the Bid object and update the Linked List's tail

I would appreciate any pointers on creating a new address for each Bid object because now the tail node only 'remembers' the first bid's address.

```
Old Tail: 0x7ffeefbfee48
New Tail: 0x7ffeefbfee48
Old Tail: 0x7ffeefbfee48
New Tail: 0x7ffeefbfee48
```

I have copied my code below omitting the parts that weren't relevant like loading bids from csv file:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include "CSVparser.hpp"

using namespace std;

// forward declarations
double strToDouble(string str, char ch);

// define a structure to hold bid information
struct Bid {
    string bidId; // unique identifier
    string title;
    string fund;
    double amount;
    Bid* nextBid; //each bid has a pointer that can point to another bid
    Bid() {
        amount = 0.0;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
    
private:
    // FIXME (1): Internal structure for list entries, housekeeping variables
    Bid* head;
    Bid* tail;
    
public:
    LinkedList();
    virtual ~LinkedList();
    void Append(Bid bid);
    void Prepend(Bid bid);
    void PrintList();
    void Remove(string bidId);
    Bid Search(string bidId);
    int Size();
};

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    // FIXME (2): Initialize housekeeping variables
    head=nullptr; //initialize head to point to nothing
    tail=nullptr;
}

void LinkedList::Append(Bid bid) { //<---I'm having trouble with this method
    // FIXME (3): Implement append logic
    if (this->head==nullptr){ //first node in a linked list
        cout << "initialize head and tail" << endl;
        this->head=&bid; //point to the bid
        this->tail=&bid;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Old Tail: " << this->tail << endl;
        this->tail->nextBid=&bid; //this refers to bid
        this->tail=&bid; //update last bid
        cout << "New Tail: " << &bid << endl;
        this->tail->nextBid=nullptr; //set pointer after last bid to null
    }
}

void displayBid(Bid bid) {
    cout << bid.bidId << ": " << bid.title << " | " << bid.amount
    << " | " << bid.fund << endl;
    return;
}

void LinkedList::PrintList() {
    // FIXME (5): Implement print logic
    //dont loop with the head, loop with bid name, because you dont want head pointer to change
    Bid* bid = this->head; //start at list's beginning
    cout << "List Head: " << this->head << endl;
    while(bid!=nullptr){
        displayBid(*(bid));
        cout << "Printing Address: " << bid << endl;
        bid = bid->nextBid; //move to the next bid
    }
}

Bid getBid() {
    Bid bid;
    //enter bid title, amount, etc.    
    return bid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    // process command line arguments
    string csvPath = "eBid_Monthly_Sales_Dec_2016.csv";
    
    LinkedList bidList;
    
    Bid bid;
    
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 9) {
        cout << "Menu:" << endl;
        cout << "  1. Enter a Bid" << endl;
        cout << "  2. Load Bids" << endl;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:{
                Bid addBid;
                cout << "new Bid Object's address is " << &addBid << endl; //address of the pointer
                bidList.Append(addBid);
//                displayBid(bid);
                bidList.PrintList();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: `&bid` is the address of the value parameter, not what you passed there originally. I'd suppose that's not what you wanted there.

Comment: You need to know the difference between an object and a reference, you pass object and causing copy in almost every function. And there is no reason to make the destructor `virtual` in this class.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I'm still curious as to how it behaves though. If `bid` is deallocated after the function is called, why doesn't the list's head get reset to `nullptr`? Right now it remembers the address of the first bid in the list after initialization.

Comment: @st4rgut About your followup question: `bid` is now a pointer.Thus, its value is an address (like `0x34ff56...`). Specifically, it's the address of `addBid` which is created in your `main()`. So the actual value of the list's head is that address (or else: it's pointing to `addBid`). When `append()` finishes up, what would be "destroyed"? Just the value of `bid` which is the address and only the address. But a copy of that address is now saved in `head`. There is no `free()` operation going on. If you drew a sketch with pointers and objects residing in memory you would probably figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a pointer to a temporary variable in the append function

```
void LinkedList::Append(Bid bid) { //<---I'm having trouble with this method
// FIXME (3): Implement append logic
if (this->head==nullptr){ //first node in a linked list
    cout << "initialize head and tail" << endl;
    this->head=&bid; //point to the bid
    this->tail=&bid;
}
else {
    cout << "Old Tail: " << this->tail << endl;
    this->tail->nextBid=&bid; //this refers to bid
    this->tail=&bid; //update last bid
    cout << "New Tail: " << &bid << endl;
    this->tail->nextBid=nullptr; //set pointer after last bid to null
}
```

You are passing a `Bid` object to the function, NOT a pointer, then you set the `tail` pointer to point at that object, but this object ***will be deleted after the function is over*** as it is created locally. Hence, `tail` will point on a deleted object, which will result in undefined behavior (personally I get 'Segmentation fault' on Linux). As an option you can pass a pointer to the `Bid` object to the function and everything will work normally as the pointer will be set to a valid `Bid` object declared outside the function.

```
void LinkedList::Append(Bid* bid) { //<---I'm having trouble with this method
// FIXME (3): Implement append logic
if (this->head==nullptr){ //first node in a linked list
    cout << "initialize head and tail" << endl;
    this->head=bid; //point to the bid
    this->tail=bid;
}
else {
    cout << "Old Tail: " << this->tail << endl;
    this->tail->nextBid=bid; //this refers to bid
    this->tail=bid; //update last bid
    cout << "New Tail: " << bid << endl;
    this->tail->nextBid=nullptr; //set pointer after last bid to null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here in line `void LinkedList::Append(Bid bid)` `bid` is a local variable and will be deallocated after the control returns from function.

Now here `this->head=&bid; //point to the bid` you are assigning the address of the local variable `bid` to `head`, which doesn't exist outside of the scope of the function `Append`. So won't give expected results.

What you can do is dynamically allocate the node and pass its address to the `Append` method.

```
void LinkedList::Append(Bid* bid) // function signature
```

adding node :

```
Bid addBid;
bidList.Append(&addBid);
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument in `append()` shouldn't be a `Bid`, but a `Bid *`. This is because, since arguments are passed by value in functions, your bid object is just a copy of the original.
That means that when assigning `&bid` somewhere, that address will be the address of the parameter (the copied object) and not the original one.
So, when the function is done and all its memory (in the stack) gets "deallocated", so is the memory of that object, making your nodes pointing to garbage.